# adding attribute to session

Tags: scala, gatling

I want to use different login methods (Bearer or JWT) for logging in. So I've created this object to reuse in simulations:

```
object Login {
  private val login: String = ConfigObject.config("login").asInstanceOf[String]
  private val password: String = ConfigObject.config("password").asInstanceOf[String]
  private val useBearer: Boolean = ConfigObject.config("useBearer").asInstanceOf[Boolean]
  private val bearerToken: String = ConfigObject.config("authToken").asInstanceOf[String]

  var loginAction: ChainBuilder = _

  loginAction = exec { session =>
    if (useBearer) {
      val bearerTokenString = s"Bearer $bearerToken"
      session.set("token", bearerTokenString)
    } else {
      http("Login user")
        .post("/auth/token/obtain")
        .body(StringBody(s"""{ "email": "$login", "password":"$password" }""")).asJson
        .headers(Map("Content-Type" -> "application/json"))
        .check(jsonPath("$.token").saveAs("jwtToken"))
      val jwtToken = session("jwtToken").as[String]
      session.set("token", s"JWT $jwtToken")
    }
    session
  }
}
```

but when I try to build headers like this I'm getting **Failed to build request: No attribute named 'token' is defined**

```
val headers: Map[String, String] = Map(
      "Content-Type" -> "application/json",
      "Authorization" -> "${token}")
```

I'm not very familiar with scala and gatling so please guide me how to do this properly

Comment: To interpolate strings on `scala`: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html. in your `Authorization` value you have `"${token}"` (`token` value should exist in your context).

Comment: Ok. My question is how to put it into the context then

Comment: Sorry looks like you are answering on something I've never asked. Once again. I want to understand how to put it into session in order to read it from that later.

Comment: Sorry about that. Add attributes to session: https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/session_api#setting-attributes. So to access the attribute, should be with the same key as it was added. Sessions are inmutable, so if in some place something like `session.set("foo", "FOO")` is executed after you set `token`, it will be discarded and not found when you try to access it.

Comment: If you look at if statement in first peace of code in my question, you can find that I’m adding “token” into session exactly as in your answer, and in the second peace I’m trying to access “token” attribute and getting no attribute named “token”. So I did exactly as it was in documentation, but this doesn’t work. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are a couple of reasons for why your example doesn't work.

The reason setting 'token' doesn't work is that sessions are immutable - session.set returns a new session, but you're returning the initial one on the very last line of 'loginAction'

Your jwt flow also won't work. The gatling dsl defines builders that are created at startup - these are used to generate all the steps that a user will follow once they are injected. You can't create extra instructions via session functions during the simulation - which is what you're attempting to do here. So everything in your 'else' block will never be executed.

you could either handle everything within gatling actions, or change loginAgction to return a ChainBuilder rather than be a session function like this...

```
def loginAction: ChainBuilder =
  if (useBearer) {
    exec(session => session.set("token", s"Bearer $bearerToken")) //returns a new session
  } else {
    exec(http("Login user")
      .post("/auth/token/obtain")
      .body(StringBody(s"""{ "email": "$login", "password":"$password" }""")).asJson
      .headers(Map("Content-Type" -> "application/json"))
      .check(jsonPath("$.token").transform(token => s"JWT $token").saveAs("token"))
    )
  }
```

Comment: This did it. Thank you!